# Concatenated variable as selector not working (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I'm puzzled & pretty unexperienced with jQuery. I'm trying to pass back a value from a thickbox window into an input element on the parent page. To determine the right input box I'm trying to concatenate two values, one of which I successfully grab from the thickbox window and the other value is a piece of text, like example below.

```
grab_flavor = $('#flavor').val(); //contains 'apple'
alert(grab_flavor); // returns 'apple'
juice = "#" + grab_flavor + "juice";
alert(juice); // returns '#applejuice'
$(juice , top.document).val("favorited"); //doesn't seem to work...
flavor = "#apple";
juice = flavor + "juice";
$(juice , top.document).val("favorited"); // works
```

I can't seem to figure out why the first concatenation isn't working, even though it returns the right value when I display it with an alert, instead nothing happens.

I've tried a number of different ways to concatenate, but they all fail when I try to include 'grabflavor'...advice much appreciated!

update: working on a better live example...

**update 2 (final)**: figured it out...syntax was valid after all, nothing wrong with the concatenation, I just overlooked a small detail because I was dealing with very long selectors that looked the same...next time I will take a longer break so I can benefit from fresh eyes. Stubbornly obsessing to understand a problem doesn't always work so well. Thank you commenters for posting and pointing out jsfiddle and jsbin, two incredibly useful finds!

Comment: Is `$(#flavor).val()` a typo? It should be `$('#flavor').val()`

Comment: Same goes for `alert(juice); // returns 'applejuice'`. It should be `alert(juice); // returns '#applejuice'`, shouldn't it?

Comment: sorry for typos...corrected, thank you!

Comment: @mrs Juice: Why not use the modern wonder of copy-and-paste rather than retyping code you're trying to debug?

Comment: Give us some of your actual code and html, you can even try to recreate the bug on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and share it with us.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder & @ Khez
I'm figuring out how to put the relevant portion of my current project live so I can have others look at the actual code. I came up with this example because I thought it mirrored my problem well (sorry for the typos again, was exhausted when I put it up). My project is hosted locally and in the backend of WordPress, not easy to post online. Will try something with jsbin/jsfiddle next and update it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's another typo during transcription, the problem is here:

```
juice = "#" + grabflavor + "juice";
```

You're missing the underscore in `grab_flavor`. Correct that, and it works ([**live copy**](http://jsbin.com/egoqa5/2)).

Comment: This works, thank you! There must be some other problem in the environment of my original code (the missing underscore was a typo as you suspected) but at least I know it should work in principal.